# Is "V Vないにかかわらず" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, words

In my textbook, they list the example sentence:

> 来る来ないにかかわらず、連絡をください。

This「来る来ない」part looks strange to me. Is it incorrect? If so, then how should it be fixed? Would it need to be 「来る？来ないにかかわらず」?

EDIT: It looks like my question was edited which is fine, but now I have another question to add if that is the case. What other verbs are okay with this grammatical structure? 「来る来ない」 is the only one I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct. You can also say

> 来るか来ないかにかかわらず、連絡をください。
>   来ると来ないとにかかわらず、連絡をください。 (old fashioned)

This construction is productive. You can do it with other verbs as well.