# What's the meaning of しない as in …するしない？

Tags: grammar

My textbook contains the following sentence

> 参加するしないにかかわらず、必ず返事を葉書で出してください。
>   (Regardless of whether you participate or not, kindly make sure to RSVP by postcard.)

as an example of the expression 名詞＋にかかわらず. While I get the whole sentence and the にかかわらず, I'm having trouble understanding this usage of しない. I know しない

- as the ない形 of する
- as in 市内 (within the city)
- as in 竹刀 (bamboo sword)

but none of these three seem to make sense, and the first one isn't even a 名詞.

Could someone please explain しない in this context and the general pattern of how/when to use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's the negative of する、しない. The point missing in the textbook is that this pattern is either 'noun + にかかわらず' or 'verb + opposite verb + にかかわらず', e.g.

- するしないにかかわらず
- 来る来ないにかかわらず
- etc.

See also [Is "V Vないにかかわらず" grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6202/is-v-v%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A-grammatical) and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JLPT_Guide/JLPT_N2_Grammar (search for "にかかわらず").

Answer (score 4):

This `しない` is simply the negative of `する`; "don't do".  The `参加するしない` part of the sentence means, regardless (`～にかかわらず`) of if you participate (`参加する`) or if you don't participate (`参加しない`).

With this form for "regardless of" (`～にかかわらず`; also could be `～を問わず`), if often takes contrasting or "opposite" ideas.  So the `参加するしない` is a compact way to list the two choices of participating or not.  I think it would also be grammatically correct to say `参加するかしないかにかからわず`, but I'm not 100% certain on that.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused why this is given explicitly to illustrate 'noun + にかかわらず'. How can a verbform be a noun?

Comment: Clearly it's not limited to nouns.  I can only say that sometimes textbooks do things like that, that make you scratch your head.